# Support For Utf-8 Using Progress Data Server For Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, utf-8, progress-4gl, openedge

I am using progress 10.2B with Oracle 9i as back end DB with use of progress data server for oracle. I created one schema holder and started it with parameters:

```
 "-cpinternal UTF-8 -cpstream UTF-8 -cpterm UTF-8 -cpcase Basic -cpcoll basic".
```

Now I am connecting same schema holder and Oracle DB (residing on same server) from editor. While connecting to Oracle I am not specifying any data service name or port number. Once connected with above configuration, I am able to update data in table in Arabic form. Now when I am using service name and port number (of orabroker residing on same server) to connect to my schema and oracle DB, I am not able to update data in Arabic and some random data like "��������" is coming. Do I need to do any changes for UTF support for Orabroker? Are there any parameters for same?

Comment: The "DataServer for Oracle" documentation has an entire chapter on Unicode support, have you read it? http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge102b/pdfs/dmora/dmora.pdf

Comment: Yes. I read that documentation and followed same steps. I am not sure if I have missed any small step of it.

Comment: I recommend you ask for help at the community, you will (currently) reach a larger Progress-population there than here: http://community.progress.com/

Comment: Thanks @jensd. already raised it there.

Comment: If your on an active license you should contact support by the way. https://www.progress.com/support